# Removing Words that contain non-ascii characters using Python

Tags: python, python-unicode

I am using the following function to strip out non-ascii characters

```
def removeNonAscii(s): 
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: ord(x)<128, s))

def removeNonAscii1(s): 
    return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)
```

I would now like to remove the entire word if it contains any non-ascii characters. I thought of measuring the length pre and post function application but I am confident that there is a more efficient way. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean remove non-**ascii** words?

Comment: Check all characters of the string, then find the proper characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the word based on spaces, something like this might work:

```
def containsNonAscii(s):
    return any(ord(i)>127 for i in s)

words = sentence.split()
cleaned_words = [word for word in words if  not containsNonAscii(word)]
cleaned_sentence = ' '.join(cleaned_words)
```

Note that this will collapse repeated whitespace into just one space.

Comment: his function already does the `join`. No need to use a list comprehension

Comment: True, but I assume a redefinition of his function. That not be completely clear...I'll edit in a new version as well.

Answer (score 1):

The most clean (but not necessarily most efficient) way is to convert a word to a binary and *attempt* to decode it as ASCII. If the attempt fails, the word has non-ASCII characters:

```
def is_ascii(w):
  try:
    w.encode().decode("us-ascii")
    return True
  except UnicodeEncodeError:
    return False
```

Comment: @JonClements No need. `decode()` does not raise any other exceptions. But ok.

Comment: But `decod` or a mistyped "us-ascii" etc... will.... The rule of thumb is to always catch something you know how to handle and let the rest propagate until it can be. A bare `except` will capture and mask everything and all you'll know is that your function is returning `False` even though it shouldn't etc...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following function. I removes all words that contain any ASCII character but probably the range can be extended as desired.

```
def removeWordsWithASCII(s):
    " ".join(filter(lambda x: not re.search(r'[\x20-\x7E]', x), s.split(' ')))
```